Postgresql pgvector: How to set a default value to a vector when its size is large?
Say I have a very large vector, I want to set all its indices to some default value. How can I achieve this? I seached online but couldn't find an answer. Note that this is not a postgresql array, this is for a pgvector vector. But maybe the answer is the same.

What did you try?  What went wrong?  Why do you think the size matters?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@jjanes, I wasn't able to find any reference for doing something like this, didn't know where to even start. I mentioned size because in node, pg module queries need to stay in a certain number of characters so I can't use node to set a vector value for a vector that large.
